# Bundle identifier for individual program

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store, provisioning-profile

I have newly opened account of 99$ as individual iOS Developer. I have another account as iOS developer as a company. In company account i gave the bundle identifier as com.mycompanyname.appname but i am confused what should i give the bundle identifier for the individual program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle ID's work the same regardless of wether the account is a company or not. Think of it more along the lines of:

> com.myDevAccountName.myAppName

From Apple's documentation on Bundle ID's

> The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that
>   contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.)
>   characters. The string should be in reverse-DNS format. For example,
>   if your company’s domain is Ajax.com and you create an app named
>   Hello, you could assign the string com.Ajax.Hello as your app’s bundle
>   ID.